# Javascript: Form Validation remove error messages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a Contact form and when I'm using the error messages when the infos aren't correct it works but I can't remove the messages once it's corrected.

What's wrong/missing in my code please?

Here's my code :

```js
// Get Data
const nom = document.querySelector("#nom");
const prenom = document.querySelector("#prenom");
const email = document.querySelector("#email");
const message = document.querySelector("#message");
const success = document.querySelector("#success");
const errorNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".error");

// Validate Data

    clearMessages ();
    let errorFlag = false;

function validateForm(){
    errorNodes[0].innerText = "";
    errorNodes[1].innerText = "";

    if(nom.value.length < 1){
        errorNodes[0].innerText = "Le nom ne peut pas être vide.";
        errorFlag = true;
    }

    if(prenom.value.length < 1){
        errorNodes[1].innerText = "Le prénom ne peut pas être vide.";
        errorFlag = true;
    }

    if(!errorFlag){
        success.innerText = "Message envoyé!";
    }
}

// Clear error / success messages
function clearMessages(){
    for (let i = 0; i < errorNodes.length; i++){
        errorNodes[i].innerText = "";
    }
    success.innerText = "";
}

// Check if email is valid
function emailIsValid(email){
    let pattern = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return pattern.test(email);
}
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}

body {
    background: #5a8cdb;
}

form {
    max-width: 550px;
    width: 90%;
    background: white;
    margin: 90px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.item label {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.item input, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

input[type="text"]:focus, textarea:focus {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5a8cdb;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 3px;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #5a8cdb;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #5a8cdb;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #3F73C5;
}

.error {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
    color: red;
}

.error-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#success {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Formulaire de Contact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateForm()">

        <h1>Contactez-nous</h1><br>

    <div class="item">
        <label for="nom">Nom</label>
        <input type="text" id="nom" placeholder="Votre nom">
        <small class="error"></small>       

        <label for="prenom">Prénom</label>
        <input type="text" id="prenom" placeholder="Votre prénom">
        <small class="error"></small>

        <div class="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Envoyez">
            <p id="success"></p>

    </div>

    </form>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

..........................................................................
.........................................................................

Comment: you can create a listener. when input is changed, the listener must call 'clearMessages()'

Comment: How could I do that please? i'm debuting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you have to call 'clearMessages()' after editing input somehow. or during editing.

add this to js file:

```
  nom.addEventListener('change', clearMessages);
  prenom.addEventListener('change', clearMessages);

  nom.addEventListener('focus', clearMessages);
  prenom.addEventListener('focus', clearMessages);
```

EDIT :
change code in clear message to :

```
errorFlag = false;
for (let i = 0; i < errorNodes.length; i++){
    errorNodes[i].innerText = "";
}
success.innerText = "";
```

and also edit this :

```
let errorFlag = false;
clearMessages ();
```

Comment: Thanks but I got the answer  :)  now I'm dealing with my last problem, once it's all corrected and I click the "Envoyez" button it doesn't show my Validation message in green. Any ideas?

Comment: updated the code this should work @Softee

Comment: I tried it but still have the sam problem when i'm clicking on my button. No success message :/ Can you edit my code using codepen or anything? Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: https://codepen.io/Me-Bottle-O-Scrumpy/pen/QWOOYqG this is the code pen i guess. @Softee

Comment: Great, it works! The only this that I thing is weird, is that when the error message pops, once you click in the field, the messages gets aways. Is this normal? I'd like it to stay until I click on the button and then I get the validation message. is it possible?

Comment: ok i removed the listeners. check it now @Softee

Comment: AMAZING !! You saved my life, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have necessary code when everything is correct within validateForm method. So either add statement that if everything is okay, will remove the the error messages with `innerHTML = ''` or instead of calling the validation on formSubmit you can:

```
nom.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => { 
if(e.target.value < 1) 
//show error code 
else //remove error  
})
```

This can be added to every input you want to validate.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the validateForm(), clear them before it does anything else

```
function validateForm(){
errorNodes[0].innerText = "";
errorNodes[1].innerText = "";
```

Then the rest of your code and add this

```
if(!errorFlag){
errorNodes[0].innerText = "";
errorNodes[1].innerText = "";
    success.innerText = "Message envoyé!";
}
```

Easiest way

Comment: Amazin! It's working for the fields! But now I'm dealing with my last problem, once it's all corrected and I click the "Envoyez" button it doesn't show my Validation message in green. Any ideas?

Comment: just edited the file if you want to check

Answer (score 0):

It is because the code didn't call the 'clearMessages()' after checking the form is validated.
Move the 'clearMessages()' insdie the 'if(!errorFlag)' condition block so the function will call 'clearMessages()' once the form is submit with no error.

```
if(!errorFlag){
        success.innerText = "Message envoyé!";
        clearMessages ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I got the answer :) now I'm dealing with my last problem, once it's all corrected and I click the "Envoyez" button it doesn't show my Validation message in green. Any ideas?